# c++ webassembly: returning a pointer on a array bigger than 128 gives zeros

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I'm using c++ webassembly to return a pointer on an array containing:

1. A pointer on a std::vector.
2. The size of the array.

When I'm setting with setNumb(), an array smaller than 128, everything works fine, but when I'm setting it bigger it returns me only zeros.

c++

```
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
class MyClass
{
public:
    int myNum;
    std::string myString;
    std::vector<float> myVector;
};
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
MyClass myObj;

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void setNumb(int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        myObj.myVector.push_back(i * 1.5111);
    }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
unsigned *getNumb()
{
    float *myVectorP = &myObj.myVector[0];
    unsigned *results = new unsigned[2];
    results[0] = (unsigned)myVectorP;
    results[1] = (unsigned)myObj.myVector.size();
    return results;
}
```

Javascript:

```
 //_Z7setNumbi(170); // give zeros
 _Z7setNumbi(128); // works
 let ptr = _Z7getNumbv();
 let container = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer, ptr, 2);
 let arrSize = container[1];
 let arr = new Float32Array(memory.buffer, container[0], arrSize);
 console.log( arr, arrSize);
```

Comment: The logging uses `arr2Size` instead of `arrSize`. You also leak memory with `new unsigned[2];`. Is the `arrSize` equal to 170?

Comment: arr2Size is a copy/paste mistake on StackOverflow, I will edit the question, thank you. arrSize is effectively equal to 170. I use new unsigned[2], because myVectorP is just a pointer, so it is just an integer that I return to the javascript. This pointer points to the beginning of my vector containing my floats.

Comment: Is there some other functions that you execute that are not in the code here? Maybe they clear the array values? Also keep in mind that WebAssembly stores the integer values in little-endian, but the Uint32Array uses the default endianness of the computer. To avoid that a DataView can be used, to ensure that you always read little-endian integers in the JavaScript side. Additionally you have to always compile the C++ code for 32 bit integers to ensure proper alignment.

Comment: No other function is executed, and the computer use little-endian.

Comment: What is the value of `container[0]`? It is clear that it is a memory pointer, but still, what it is? For both calls 128 and 170. I would personally avoid the creation of the `unsigned[2]` array and will have two functions, one to return me the pointer, other to return me the length. Returning an array from a single function call is probably more expensive than two calls returning non-array values.

Comment: In container[0], for 128 I get the number 5245680 and for 170 I get  5246200.
But I m not returning an array anyway? I'm returning just one pointer that points to an array containing both.
And I noticed in fact that not everything is 0.
For 170, everything is zero until 128. Then I got the correct values for the last 42 ones.
For 300 I got 0 until 256, then I got the good values.
So I basically have the correct entries as a modulo of 128.

Comment: That is so strange, I'm starting to worry about the sanity of the C++ compiler or the interpreter of WebAssembly, you are using. I would see for new versions. Maybe you try `push_back(i);` to see what the result will be. It could be some float/int conversion issue. Maybe to try to use uint32 instead of float32 (both C++/JavaScript sides), and if it works, then there is a bug related to the floats conversion.

Comment: I tried push_back(i), and I used uint32 on both sides. Nothing changed.
But I found something, I could make it work, but I had to set the values of myVector directly in the getNumb() function. And I could keep the declaration of the vector inside MyClass.

Comment: I see. I would try to make the `myObj` a dynamic object. There could be something related to that. You could also manage the array yourself, with `realloc` and cast it. It seems that some other function clears the memory in between the calls. Maybe you could check the values in getNum's first line (in the C++ side), before taking the pointer, to confirm that they are not zeroes (except the first one, that shall be zero). If they are zeroes, well...something clears the memory between the calls.